# Android Studio 2.3 is generating unaligned signed APK's instead of zipaligned?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-studio-2.3, zipalign

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.3 and now I was going to generate a signed APK for one of my existing apps using `Build / Generate signed APK...` just as I've always done. Before I have always gotten a file called `MyApp-1.0.apk` (where `1.0` is the version name), but now I get `MyApp-1.0-unaligned.apk`.

I noticed there are some new options to choose `V1 (Jar signature)` and/or `V2 (Full APK Signature`. I selected both, as [recommended in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2). The documentation does however say this

> **Caution:** If you sign your app using APK Signature Scheme v2 and make further changes to the app, the app's signature is invalidated. For this reason, use tools such as zipalign before signing your app using APK Signature Scheme v2, not after.

In my `build.gradle` I have

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        // Enable/disable ProGuard for debug build
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```

I've seen some people experiencing similar problems with alpha releases of the Android gradle build tool, but I'm using `2.3.0`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

So how do I make the APK-generation process zipalign my APK's before signing them?

Comment: Could you output the result of "zipalign -c -v 4 <path-to-apk>"?

Comment: I though since Android 2.2.0 it doesn't produce the unaligned version. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223551

Comment: @ Isuru `zipalign -c -v 4 <path-to-apk>` returns a long list of lines and finally at the bottom a `Verification succesful` [sic]. I thought the documentation says that you can't zipalign an application that's been signed with V2? I'm using build tools 25.0.2 by the way. Been signing using the menu command in Android Studio for years with no problems, but I recently updated Android Studio, build tools, SDK, everything...

Comment: I had the same problem and I did create a C# program to compile unaligned apk to release version. But I have no idea why this occurs in new version of Android Studio.

Comment: @Isuru The strange thing is that it seems the APK **is** zipaligned, even though `-unaligned` is added to the filename... First, the terminal command you mentioned earlier seems to verify that the APK is aligned, and secondly I just tried uploading it to the Play Store without any problem... that wouldn't work with a nonaligned APK, right?

Comment: @Isuru Problem solved, my bad, see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by having an external gradle script manage the filename of generated APK's. I had totally forgot about that script, and now it had started failing a check to see if the APK is zipaligned, since Google introduced the v2 signing.

I had the script included in my `build.gradle` like this

```
apply from: '../../export_signed_apk.gradle'
```

And the script itself looked like this

```
android.applicationVariants.all {
    variant -> def appName

    //Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
    if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
        appName = applicationName
    } else {
        appName = parent.name
    }

    variant.outputs.each {
        output -> def newApkName

        //If there's no ZipAlign task it means that our artifact will be unaligned and we need to mark it as such.
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        } else {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}-unaligned.apk"
        }

        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
    }
}
```

It seems that `output.zipAlign` fails since applying the V2 signing, so it would return `myApp-1.0-unaligned` even when the signed APK was indeed zipaligned.

I simply removed the IF statement, and am just keeping

```
newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
```